# Fieldnames with special characters in jq string interpolation

Tags: json, jq

I have a logfile with entries like this:

```json
{"@timestamp":"2024-02-28T10:21:51.939Z", "log.level":"info", "msg": "done"}
```

I want to convert this json into something like this:

```
2024-02-28T10:21:51.939Z - info - done
```

This is the output I get from my shell commands:

```
$ msg='{"@timestamp":"2024-02-28T10:21:51.939Z", "log.level":"info", "msg": "done"}'

$ echo $msg | jq -r '"\(.[\"log.level\"])"'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
"\(.[\"log.level\"])"     
jq: 1 compile error

$ echo $msg | jq -r '"\(.msg)"'
done

$ echo $msg | jq -r '"\(.[\"@timestamp\"])"'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
"\(.[\"@timestamp\"])"     
jq: 1 compile error

$ echo $msg | jq -r '"\(.@timestamp)"'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_INTERP_END, expecting QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
"\(.@timestamp)"              
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
"\(.@timestamp)"   
jq: 2 compile errors
```

I'm using bash on Ubuntu. jq-1.6

Comment: These work: `echo "$msg" | jq -r '"\(.["log.level"])"'` or `echo "$msg" | jq -r '"\(."log.level")"'` or `echo "$msg" | jq -r '.["log.level"]'` or ``echo "$msg" | jq -r '."log.level"'``. See [Object Identifier-Index](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#object-identifier-index) and [String Interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed my own problem. In contrast to the manual, you don't have to escape the quotes.

```
$ echo $msg | jq -r '"\(.["@timestamp"])"'
2024-02-28T10:21:51.939Z

$ echo $msg | jq -r '"\(.["log.level"])"'
info
```

Comment: It's not in contrast to the manual. Under [String interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation), it says "Inside a string, you can put an expression inside parens after a backslash.". Expressions don't need to escape quotes.

Comment: I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways:

```bash
# if you don't like working with blackslashes
echo $msg | jq -r '[.["@timestamp","log.level","msg"]]|join(" - ")'         

# if you want all the values (which in your case you do)
echo $msg | jq -r 'values|join(" - ")'

# to_entries if you want to manipulate value
echo $msg | jq -r 'to_entries|map(.value)|join(" - ")'
echo $msg | jq -r 'to_entries|map(.value|ascii_upcase)|join(" - ")'

# without using map
echo $msg | jq -r '[to_entries[].value]|join(" - ")'
```